# Conversion from String to Long not valid

Tags: vb.net, file, active-directory

I am creating a VB Windows form which retrieves a list of computers registered in AD and then checks each Computer for the existence of an application (looks for the .exe). I am having trouble with concatenating the path to the .exe I receive an error 'Conversation from String to Long is not Valid'

How do I fix this?

```
Private Sub CheckButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckButton.Click

    Dim PCsource As String = "C:\FilePath\adComputers.txt"
    Dim FilepathX64 As String = "\C$\Program Files (x86)\FilePath\Some.exe"
    Dim FilepathX86 As String = "\C$\Program Files\FilePath\Some.exe"
    Dim Check As String
    Dim Install As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Dim Installed As System.IO.StreamWriter

    If System.IO.File.Exists(PCsource) = True Then
        Dim Computer As New System.IO.StreamReader(PCsource)
        Do While Computer.Peek() <> -1
            Check = Computer.ReadLine()
            If System.IO.File.Exists("\\" & Check & FilepathX64 Or "\\" & Check & FilepathX86) = True Then
                Installed = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\FilePath\Installed.txt", True)
                Installed.WriteLine("Sophos is installed on " & Check, True)
                Installed.Close()
            Else
                Install = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\FilePath\Install.txt", True)
                Install.WriteLine(Check, True)
                Install.Close()
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        FailSound.Play()
        MessageBox.Show("The Domain Computer List is missing")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the ***exact*** text of the error message, which should also include information on which line is failing.

Comment: You really shouldn't be hard coding values like that in a compiled program. Is there any reason why you can't use a scripting language like PowerShell which is ideal for this kind of thing?

Comment: you should definitely explore the powershell option. It is made exactly for stuff like that.

Comment: A String and a Long are at a bar...

Comment: Error: Conversion from string "\\COMPUTERNAME\C$\Program Fil" to type 'Long' is not valid

Comment: This application is for a specific situation, the domain computers are all running the same image so for this particular scenario a hard coded path shouldn't cause any problem....thank you for the comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you CANNOT do this.

```
if System.IO.File.Exists("\\" & Check & FilepathX64 Or "\\" & Check & FilepathX86) = True then
```

but you can do this

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists("\\" & Check & FilepathX64) = True) or (System.IO.File.Exists("\\" & Check & FilepathX86) = True) then
```

[using file.exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you MutedDisk that was perfect.... tried to up vote but don't have enough Rep

Comment: @RootUser it's okay you have accepted the answer. have a good one bud

Comment: You may wish to change `Or` to `OrElse` so the code will short circuit properly if the first file is found.  This code will check for both files, even if the first is found.  If the first is found, the second check is not necessary.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway good point. Because he's playing with 64 and 32 bits environment it should be actually if elseif else end if. Many ways for the same result depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, a simple PowerShell method:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * |
    ForEach-Object {
        if (Test-Path "\\$($_.Name)\c$\Program Files\FilePath\Some.exe" -or
            Test-Path "\\$($_.Name)\c$\Program Files (x86)\FilePath\Some.exe")
        { "Sophos is installed on $($_.Name)" }
        else { "Sophos is not installed on $($_.Name)" }
    }
```

Theres plenty of scope for improvement, using `Test-Connection` to whittle out computers that are offline or limiting the computers to a specific list as in the original example.